# Visual Tool Bar for HTML/JS components in Apatana

Tags: user-interface, aptana

I am looking for the Visual GUI designer in Aptana similar to one in Visual Studio.
But I could not find one. Without the Visual toolbar ( where I can drag and drop components) how will I develop web pages efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio is designed for users who like to code their HTML and CSS directly. As such, there is content assist that can help you compose your tags and styles, but there is currently no GUI editor. You may find that for HTML-5 based pages, GUI editors don't help substantially for more modern layouts.